# Почему во многих языках индексирование начинается с 0?

Tags: любой-язык

По-моему, это из электроники, разве нет?
С чего вообще это пошло?

Comment: Предположим, что у вас есть массив из целых чисел, каждое по четыре байта. Массив расположен в памяти последовательно. Чтобы получить элемент N, надо взят указатель на массив и прибавить к нему (N - 1) * 4 байт, или, если вести отсчет от нуля, просто N * 4 байта

Comment: @Etki: А почему не как ответ?

Comment: В электронике отсчет ножек многих микросхем тоже начинаются с 0. Я думал это связано...

Comment: @VladD потому что это просто мои догадки

Comment: На линейке первая цифра тоже 0! координата первого значения начинается с нулевой точки.

Comment: мне лень переводить, но большинство серьезных причин  - приведено здесь https://www.quora.com/Why-do-array-indexes-start-with-0-zero-in-many-programming-languages/answer/Travis-Addair И там ссылка на статью Дейкстры

Comment: вообще, почему изначально пошло - потому, что математики вряд ли стали бы исключать 0 как точку отсчета, а потом уже обоснования (типа приведенного выше пошли)

Comment: В первом (или одном из первых) языке ВУ -- Фортране индексы массивов были с 1, в последующем -- (из широко известных) Алголе требовалось явно указывать граничные индексы, а вот в Си (не уверен, что он был первым) все это упростили (сделали с 0) и оно приняло привычные очертания...

Comment: В Lua с 1 начинаются..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В первую очередь потому, что с точки зрения реализации понятие "индекса" элемента в непрерывном агрегате напрямую связано с понятием "смещения" элемента от начала агрегата в памяти. Понятно, что смещение самого первого элемента агрегата равно нулю. Соответственно и индекс его разумно взять равным нулю.

Другими словами, как ни верти, но индекс первого элемента в агрегате все равно придется пересчитывать в значение `0` на машинном уровне. В такой ситуации реализация индексации с ненулевой базой будет всегда волей-неволей подразумевать неявное приведение ее к индексации с нулевой базой. В многих языках программирования просто не считают необходимым это делать. Зачем, действительно?

Comment: При выделении динамической памяти в C/C++ возвращаемый указатель не обязательно указывает на начало выделенного из кучи участка памяти.

Comment: @hunter: А какое это имеет значение в данном случае? Главное, чтобы указатель указывал на начало пользовательской области памяти, т.е. на ту точку, от которой будут отсчитываться смещения. А то, что блок может также содерждать какие-то служебные области со служебными данными к данному вопросу не относится никак. Что именно вы хотели сказать?

Comment: то и хочу сказать что даже при выделении не фрагментированной области памяти из указателя на нулевой элемент рано или поздно может возникнуть необходимость получить указатель на ячейку памяти с меньшим адресом.

Comment: @hunter: Прекрасно. Но какое это имеет отношение к теме индексации? "Ячейка с меньшим адресом" не является частью пользовательских данных, и доступаться к ней путем отрицательной индексации пользовательских данных никто не будет (в здравом уме). Такая область памяти будет прекрасно доступна путем вычета некоего известного платформе смещения из указателя "пользовательского" уровня и все. Я по прежнему не вижу, какое это все имеет отношение к рассматриваемой теме или к моему ответу.

Comment: @AnT,  первым таким языком (по умолчанию индексы с 0) был Си? Или какой-то до него?

Comment: @avp: До языка С были языки B и BCPL с той же самой нулевой индексацией. Язык С унаследовал свой подход к массивам именно из B и BCPL, с одним важным изменением. В B и BCPL массивы физически реализовались через обычные указатели. В С физические указатели убрали, но стали их "эмулировать" (пресловутый "array type decay"). А все остальное в С осталось, как в B и BCPL именно для облегчения обратной совместимости с этими языками.

Comment: "В такой ситуации реализация индексации с ненулевой базой будет всегда волей-неволей подразумевать неявное приведение ее к индексации с нулевой базой." -- для указанного вами непрерывного агрегата это неявное приведение как раз и есть вычитание заранее известного смещения. Оно есть всегда, в т.ч. и при нулевой индексации. Разницы между разными индексациями нет.

Comment: @hunter: Это откуда же оно возьмется при нулевой индексации-то? Пусть у меня в руках есть указатель `p` на начало моего агрегата. Пусть это массив с элементами размера `s`. Тогда при индексации по базе `0` доступ к i-тому элементу массива будет делаться по [байтовой] формуле `p + i * s`. Все. А для индексации по любой другой базе `k` формула будет иметь вид `p + (i - k) * s` или, эквивалентно, `p + i * s - K`. Видите дополнительное вычитание? А при нулевой индексации его нет.

Comment: @AnT, "даже при выделении не фрагментированной области памяти из указателя на нулевой элемент рано или поздно может возникнуть необходимость получить указатель на ячейку памяти с меньшим адресом". В частности функция free() обращается к ячейке памяти с меньшим адресом, получая оттуда информацию о длине массива (благодаря этому ей для освобождения передаётся только указатель без размера освобождаемой памяти).

Comment: @hunter: И? К чему это? Я по-прежнему в упор не вижу связи того, что вы здесь повторяете, с темой дискуссии. Какое отношение к рассматриваемой теме имеет структура блока, выделенного `malloc` и разбираемого потом `free`? Мы говорим о доступе к элементам некоего пользовательского агрегата. При чем здесь то, что будет когда-то делать `free`?

Comment: @AnT, "вычитание заранее известного смещения. Оно есть всегда, в т.ч. и при нулевой индексации". Потому что до нулевого элемента есть полезная информация.
"Это откуда же оно возьмется при нулевой индексации-то" -- вот при использовании free и возьмётся. Освобождать память рано или поздно всё равно придётся.

Comment: @hunter: Мое исходное утверждение заключается в том, что мы работаем с неким массивом `a[100]` и в процессе выполняем *массовую* операцию доступа к элементам `a[i]`. Вот именно эта операция индексного доступа будет выполняться естественнее при нулевой индексации (по причинам, который я привел выше). А то, что когда-нибудь нам может понадобиться освободить `a` через `free` и для этого доступиться по отрицательному смещению... нас это совершенно не заботит. Надо - доступимся. Не проблема. Нас эта одноразовая операция совершенно не волнует. Она никак не влияет на доступ `a[i]`.

Comment: @AnT, "Вот именно эта операция индексного доступа", "Нас эта одноразовая операция совершенно не волнует." -- если вы хотите сказать что операция доступа по индексу выполняется чаще, чем операция освобождения, то вы 1) ограничили множество рассматриваемых программ 2) заставляете программиста выполнять вместо компилятора работу по оптимизации.

Отмечу что тот же Дейкстра (https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) пишет о том, что такая индексация будет удобнее для человека, а не для компилятора.

Comment: @hunter Я хочу сказать только то, что мой ответ базируется, как в нем сказано открытым текстом, именно и только на соображениях естественности реализации доступа к явным элементам пользовательского агрегатного типа. Ни больше, ни меньше. И я разрешаю Дийкстре иметь свои соображения по этому вопросу (пока они не противоречат моим, разумеется :) )

Comment: @AnT, я хочу сказать только то, что заставлять программиста использовать определённый тип индексации только потому что он естественен при исполнении -- это всё равно что заставлять программиста писать на asm или сразу на машинных кодах. Всё равно ж компилировать будем в них :)

Comment: @hunter Сейчас - возможно. Но подход к индексации в языке С зарождался в те времена, когда он был существенно ближе к asm и ничего удивительного в том, чтобы при написании программ на С размышлять в терминах asm, никто не видел. Да и сегодня я не вижу в этом ничего зазорного, когда речь идет о С и С-подобных языках.